# Execute other SQL query if first one was empty for set of elements to eliminate PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreach

I get row data with query:

```
SELECT itemNAME FROM item_list WHERE itemID ='$itemID' AND itemSUB ='$itemSUB'
```

If result is empty I query again with:

```
SELECT itemNAME FROM item_list WHERE itemID ='$itemID'
```

Morover it's ran in a loop like:

```
foreach ($dataBuffor as $dataItem) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT itemNAME FROM item_list WHERE itemID ='$itemID' AND itemSUB ='$itemSUB'");
    $fetched_data = mysql_fetch_row($query);
    $itemNAME = $fetched_data[0];

    if ($itemNAME == "") {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT itemNAME FROM item_list WHERE itemID ='$itemID'");
        $fetched_data = mysql_fetch_row($query);
        $itemNAME = $fetched_data[0];
    }
}
```

How to redo this query to ask once for a set of data (insead looping for it) and include empty result logic in query itself?

I expect to produce something like:

```
SELECT itemNAME FROM item_list WHERE itemID ='$itemID' AND itemSUB ='$itemSUB' 
if itemNAME == '' (
    SELECT itemNAME FROM item_list WHERE itemID ='$itemID'
)
```

That will result with array of results to not have to foreach the SQL query itself (which is horribly bad)

Comment: Are you looking for an empty result set, or do you actually have a row whose name is `""`?

Comment: Why don't your queries use anything from `$dataItem`? You're doing the same two queries every time through the loop.

Comment: @Barmar The row can be "" or empty. `Why don't your queries use anything from` it's pseudo code & the whole loop is to be removed as I stated

Comment: What does merging the two queries have to do with the need for the loop?

Comment: What if there's no row with a matching `itemSUB`, but there are multiple rows with matching `itemID`? Is there a criteria to select which of the latter, or is any of them acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution, as chained with this question: [SQL queries inside IN() clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596460/sql-queries-inside-in-clause) is as follows. Thank You @RobBaillie and other contributors!

```
SELECT *
FROM item_list
WHERE itemNAME
= ( SELECT itemNAME
    FROM   item_list
    WHERE  itemID = '17'
    AND    (itemSUB ='1' OR itemSUB ='0')
    ORDER  BY itemSUB DESC
    LIMIT  1)
OR itemName
= ( SELECT itemNAME
    FROM   item_list
    WHERE  itemID = '57'
    AND    (itemSUB ='0' OR itemSUB ='0')
    ORDER  BY itemSUB DESC
    LIMIT  1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT itemNAME, IF(itemSUB ='$itemSUB', 1, 0) AS `Rank`
FROM item_list
WHERE (itemID ='$itemID')
ORDER BY `Rank` DESC
```

This will return a query of the elements that match both criteria first, and then those that match just one

Comment: Though it won't matter which one - there is a requirement that itemID MUST match - only itemSUB is an optional match.

Comment: `x OR (x AND y)` is equivalent to `x`.

Comment: There's no need to test `itemID = '$itemID'` in the `IF`, since that's guaranteed by `WHERE`.

Comment: ok ok, I removed the OR, I thought it would be clearer with that OR, anyway, the "big" part is the IF not the WHERE

Comment: The `IF` only needs to test `itemSUB`.

Comment: Thank you guys its now a group effort :)

Comment: I've got enough rep, I don't always need to be the one answering -- I enjoy prodding :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
SELECT itemNAME
FROM   item_list
WHERE  itemID = '$itemID'
AND    ( itemSUB ='$itemSUB' OR itemSUB IS NULL )
ORDER BY itemSUB DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If there's row with a matching itemSUB, it'll be first in the set and therefore returned, if not then the row will be the one with NULL

If you are looking for a list a `$itemID`, you can use an `IN` - though it's not trivial.

```
SELECT itemID, itemNAME
FROM   item_list
WHERE  ( itemID, itemSUB ) IN ( $itemIdAndSubList )
OR     ( itemID IN ( $itemIdList ) AND itemSUB ID NULL )
ORDER BY itemID, itemSUB DESC
```

Now this is a little bit of an odd one - the first 'IN' you are matching ( `$itemIdAndSubList` ) is not matching a single column, it's matching a pair of columns (a tuple, to give it it's proper name).

The list needs to be in this form:

```
( itemID1, itemSUB1 ), ( itemID2, itemSUB2 ), ( itemID3, itemSUB3 )
```

I'd say you'll need to build it yourself in PHP.

`$itemIdList` is simpler, in the form:

```
itemID1, itemID2, itemID3
```

You will end up with something along the lines of this being sent to mysql (newlines added for format clarity only):

```
SELECT itemID, itemNAME
FROM   item_list
WHERE  ( itemID, itemSUB ) IN ( ( itemID1, itemSUB1 ),
                                ( itemID2, itemSUB2 ),
                                ( itemID3, itemSUB3 ) )
OR     ( itemID IN ( itemID1,
                     itemID2,
                     itemID3 ) AND itemSUB ID NULL )
ORDER BY itemID, itemSUB DESC
```

Once you get the results back into PHP you'll need to loop over them and pull out the ones you want.

As they are ordered by itemID, then you can just take the first record for each given itemID and it should be the one you want.

Something along the lines of:

```
$itemNames = array();
foreach( $fetched_data as $fetched_row ) {
    if (!isset( $fetched_row[ 'itemID' ] ) {
       $itemNames[ $fetched_row[ 'itemID' ] ] = $fetched_row[ 'itemNAME' ];
    }
}
```

`$itemNames` will then contain the data you need.

I hope that makes sense - try to put it together and see how far you get.

Comment: Add `LIMIT 1` and it will be the only row returned.

Comment: This works @RobBaillie, but now how to query if I have more then one `SELECT` to do? For example I have 10 different sets of `itemID`s

Comment: Trickier, but you can use the "IN" construct, tweak the ORDER BY and then loop over the result set picking out the ones you need.  Will edit to give you hints - but you'll have to try it out yourself to get to the full answer.

Comment: I should point out that my answer assumes that itemSUB should match, or be NULL - looking at your original question again I'm not sure that this is what you asked for...

Answer (score 0):

The best way in my opinion. Please try this:

```
SELECT a.itemNAME 
FROM item_list a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT itemNAME 
           FROM item_list 
           WHERE itemID ='$itemID') b
ON(a.itemSUB=b.itemSUB) 
WHERE a.itemID ='$itemID' AND a.itemSUB ='$itemSUB'
```

Comment: The subquery doesn't return `b.itemSUB`.

Answer (score -2):

First fix your WHERE clause so you can have `itemID='$itemID' OR itemSUB=$itemSUB`

You could try using something like:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {
    print $row;
}
```

That way you run the query once, then every time you call fetch_row you get a new row from the mysql cursor.

As soon as your query runs out of results, $row will be null and the while loop will finish.

Comment: How does this help with changing the `WHERE` criteria depending on the previous result?

Comment: he isn't using the foreach loop to change his where conditional though.

Comment: But I have `temID ='$itemID' AND itemSUB ='$itemSUB'` I know I have to `SELECT itemNAME FROM item_list WHERE itemID ='$itemID'`. It's nessesary

Comment: Sigh, minus 1 for me... yet the OPs code is some of the worst I have seen.

Comment: -1 because your answer isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: he's not asking how to get multiple rows, he just wants a single row. He wants the row that matches two conditions if it exists, otherwise he wants the row that matches just one condition.

Comment: pretty sure he is looping over his code without even using the dataItem object in the foreach loop.