# SQL queries inside IN() clause

Tags: sql, in-clause

I have `SELECT` query based on `IN()` clause, where I want to feed that clause with other queries like:

```
SELECT *
FROM item_list
WHERE itemNAME
IN (
    SELECT itemNAME
    FROM   item_list
    WHERE  itemID = '17'
    AND    (itemSUB ='1' OR itemSUB ='0')
    ORDER  BY itemSUB DESC
    LIMIT  1,
    SELECT itemNAME
    FROM   item_list
    WHERE  itemID = '57'
    AND    (itemSUB ='0' OR itemSUB ='0')
    ORDER  BY itemSUB DESC
    LIMIT  1
)
```

But it errors with: 
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT itemNAME FROM item_list WHERE itemID = '57' AND (itemSUB ='0' OR' at line 11`

Comment: Why do you have an Order By in an IN statement?  It's not returning any data and ItemSub isn't anything you are querying on, so this is just extra processing time.  I'm not even sure it's allowed...

Comment: When limiting a query you can use an `ORDER BY` in a subquery to ensure the proper item is returned.  At least in SQL Server that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Goat CO deleted good answer:

```
SELECT *
FROM item_list
WHERE itemNAME
= ( SELECT itemNAME
    FROM   item_list
    WHERE  itemID = '17'
    AND    (itemSUB ='1' OR itemSUB ='0')
    ORDER  BY itemSUB DESC
    LIMIT  1)
OR itemName 
= ( SELECT itemNAME
    FROM   item_list
    WHERE  itemID = '57'
    AND    (itemSUB ='0' OR itemSUB ='0')
    ORDER  BY itemSUB DESC
    LIMIT  1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you are looking for is `union all` rather than `limit`:

```
SELECT *
FROM item_list
WHERE itemNAME
IN (
    SELECT itemNAME
    FROM   item_list
    WHERE  itemID = '17'
    AND    (itemSUB ='1' OR itemSUB ='0')
    ORDER  BY itemSUB DESC
    LIMIT  1 union all
    SELECT itemNAME
    FROM   item_list
    WHERE  itemID = '57'
    AND    (itemSUB ='0' OR itemSUB ='0')
    ORDER  BY itemSUB DESC
    LIMIT  1
)
```

However, this probably will not work, because some SQL engines (notably MySQL) don't allow `limit` in such subqueries.  Instead, you can do a join:

```
SELECT il.*
FROM item_list il join
     (select *
      from ((SELECT itemNAME
             FROM   item_list
             WHERE  itemID = '17' AND (itemSUB ='1' OR itemSUB ='0')
             ORDER  BY itemSUB DESC
             LIMIT  1
            ) union
            (SELECT itemNAME
             FROM   item_list
             WHERE  itemID = '57' AND (itemSUB ='0' OR itemSUB ='0')
             ORDER  BY itemSUB DESC
             LIMIT  1
            )
           ) l
     ) l
     on il.itemName = l.itemName;
```

Comment: It should be `UNION` rather than `UNION ALL` to remove duplicates. `WHERE X IN ('foo','foo')` wouldn't return the same row twice.

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . It doesn't make a difference for the first statement (with the `in`) but it does for the second.  I was thinking about that and caught off guard by the fact that the details on the items are different -- but, of course, the name could be the same even when the details are different.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way.

```
SELECT *
FROM item_list
WHERE itemNAME
IN (
SELECT itemNAME
FROM   item_list
WHERE  
(itemID = '17'
AND    (itemSUB ='1' OR itemSUB ='0')
 )
OR
(
itemID = '57' AND    (itemSUB ='0' OR itemSUB ='0')
)

)
ORDER  BY itemSUB DESC
LIMIT  1
```

However, unless you are practising subqueries, you don't need one.  You just need this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   item_list
WHERE  
(itemID = '17'
AND    (itemSUB ='1' OR itemSUB ='0')
 )
OR
(
itemID = '57' AND    (itemSUB ='0' OR itemSUB ='0')
)
ORDER  BY itemSUB DESC
LIMIT  1
```